# Algorithm Peer Review

Tags: big-o

So I am currently taking an algorithms class and have been asked to prove

`Prove: ((n^2 / log n) + 10^5 n * sqrt(n)) / n^2 = O(n^2 / log n)`

I have come up with `n0 = 1 and c = 5` when solving it I end up with `1 <= 5` I just wanted to see if I could get someone to verify this for me.

I'm not sure if this is the right forum to post in, if it's wrong I apologize and if you could point me in the right direction to go to that would be wonderful.

Comment: No, maybe programmers.stackexchange. In any case, suggest you review the definition of big O given the the class.

Comment: Not sure ... just an guess. I think you need to show that `((n^2/log n)` grows faster than `10^5 * sqrt(n))`

Comment: Doesn't Big O, not theta, just Big O mean that it is upper bound by the answer (n^2 / log n). and by using 1 as n0 and 5 as c doesn't that  prove that it is <= c * (n^2 * log n)?

Comment: Is it: `10^(5*n)` or is it `(10^5)*n` ?

Comment: @fjardon it is (10^5)n*srt(n)

Answer (score 4):

If I am not wrong, you have to prove that the upper bound of the given function is `n^2 logn`.
Which can be the case if for `very large values of n`,

```
n^2/logn >= n * sqrt(n)
n >= sqrt(n) * log(n)
```

Since, `log(n) < sqrt(n)`, `log(n)*sqrt(n)` will always be less than `n`. Hence, our inequality is correct. So, the upper bound is `O(n^2/ logn)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the limit method process:

[image]

Thus, the solution of your case should look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming functions `f` and `g` are increasing, by definition `f(x) = O(g(x))` iff `limit x->inf f(x)/g(x)` is non-negative. If you substitute your functions for `f` and `g`, and simplify the expression, you will see that the limit trivially comes out to be `0`.